# How to place column comparison in between and writing to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

I have csv which contains the months data in float, it get randomly generated.

I wanted to compare 2 months and place the % value in-between. if I do comparison get placed at the end.

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Services.csv').fillna(0)
df.drop(df.columns[:1],axis=1,inplace=True)
a = len(df.columns)

for col in range(a-1):
    current = (df.iloc[:, col])
    col += 1
    per = ("per" , col)
    previous = (df.iloc[:, col])
    per = []
    for a, b in zip(current, previous):
        try:
            x = repr(round((a - b) / a * 100.0))
            per.append(x + "%")
        except ZeroDivisionError:        
            per.append(0)
    df['Variation %'] = per   
    print (df) ```

---

What I am getting is :
````

```
    June      July   September     August Variation %
0   0.000000e+00  0.000000    0.000000   0.000000           0
1  -8.840000e-04  0.137259    1.215444   1.378786      15627%
2  -2.500000e-02  0.697000    0.438000   0.834000       2888%
3   0.000000e+00  0.162507    0.000000   0.000000           0
4   0.000000e+00  0.000000    0.000000   0.000000           0
5   2.000000e-04  0.000855    0.000000   0.000000       -328%  
6  -6.661338e-16  0.000000    8.878000   6.405564        100%
7   1.216297e+01  0.029005    0.000000   0.025500        100%
```

---

````
what I am looking for in format like, it should compare between 2 month and place it to next column.
ex (As an image attached):
``` July    Variation%  August  Variation%  September   Variation%  October
     0.32       98%        17.58      98%     17.58      98%         17.58
````

[image: Expected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.use_inf_as_na = True # to use `inf` values as np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'July':[0.137259,0.697,0.162507,0,0],
                  'August':[1.378786,0.834,0,0,0],
                  'September':[16.39,0.068103,0.0255,0,0],
                  'October':[5.16466,17.58,0,0,0.580464]})


print(df)
```

```
       July    August  September    October
0  0.137259  1.378786  16.390000   5.164660
1  0.697000  0.834000   0.068103  17.580000
2  0.162507  0.000000   0.025500   0.000000
3  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
4  0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.580464
```

```py
def get_variation(current, previous):
    
    one_val_zero = ((current > 0) & ~(previous > 0)) | (~(current > 0) & (previous > 0)) # is current or previous value zero ?
    both_val_zero =  ~( (current > 0) | (previous > 0) ) # is both values zero
    
    variation = pd.Series( (current - previous)/current) * 100
    
    variation[one_val_zero] = 100
    variation[both_val_zero] = 0
    variation = variation.astype(int)

    return  variation



new_df = df.copy() # its necessary or you can create separate DataFrame for Variation 
variation_col_names = []

for col in range(df.shape[1] - 1):
    variation_col_name = df.columns[col][:3] + '_' + df.columns[col+1][:3]
    variation_col_names.append(variation_col_name)

    variation_col = ( get_variation(df.iloc[:,col+1], df.iloc[:,col]) ) 
    
    new_df.insert( (2*col)+1, variation_col_name, variation_col, allow_duplicates=True )

print(new_df)
```

```
       July  Jul_Aug    August  Aug_Sep  September  Sep_Oct    October
0  0.137259       90  1.378786       91  16.390000     -217   5.164660
1  0.697000       16  0.834000    -1124   0.068103       99  17.580000
2  0.162507      100  0.000000      100   0.025500      100   0.000000
3  0.000000        0  0.000000        0   0.000000        0   0.000000
4  0.000000        0  0.000000        0   0.000000      100   0.580464
```

```py
styled_df = new_df.style.format("{}%",subset=variation_col_names)
styled_df
```

```
       July   Jul_Aug    August   Aug_Sep  September   Sep_Oct    October
0  0.137259       90%  1.378786       91%  16.390000     -217%   5.164660
1  0.697000       16%  0.834000    -1124%   0.068103       99%  17.580000
2  0.162507      100%  0.000000      100%   0.025500      100%   0.000000
3  0.000000        0%  0.000000        0%   0.000000        0%   0.000000
4  0.000000        0%  0.000000        0%   0.000000      100%   0.580464
```

add

Comment: Hi Param,  Its wonderful solution, but is it also be possible to have % sign along with value and "-89%" too. since in my case its showing very different it should show the variation in "-" but there shows 100%:  2.19$ 100     0.32$

Comment: Ok first let me clear question. how do you want to calculate variation? should it be in range 0-100 and can be negative? or it can be any value out of the range 1-100.

Comment: it can be any value out of the range 1-100 or in 100. with containing negative as well, since my frame value in month july in up trend and other month it goes in down trend, negative variations  help me to know the behavior.

Comment: ok remove `abs` in the function `get_variation`  and the line `variation[variation > 100] = 100` .

Comment: I made changes to the answer with `%` sign and variation range.

Comment: Hi Param, its working as expected but in my case since its "%" has converted the value to str we are not able to do df.style, to apply color like green for (-) and red for (+).

Comment: If you want to apply style via `df.style` your column name must be unique but this DataFrame have every second column named `variation`. It can be solved if you specify unique column name for `variation` we don't have to add `%` sign in `new_df` instead we can do it by `df.style` and your variation will remain `int`. [look here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values)

Comment: Hi Param, In this cade possible to add variation along with previous month or we can go with range so that we can add color in variation along with %.

Comment: @Sidh I changed columns names and added style for `%` sign.